# Selenium - undetected_chromedriver python: How to load a packed .crx extension file to undetected_chromedriver?

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler, undetected-chromedriver

I know how to load an unpacked/extracted extension file but Is there any way to load an extension in .crx format within undetected_chromedriver?

I have been trying to automate a chrome extension and it has worked perfectly fine in the normal selenium chromedriver when I load it in the .crx format but for some reason, the extension doesn't function when I load it in the unpacked/extracted format.

Now I've been trying to use it with the undetected_chromedriver and it isn't working because seems like there is no add_extension() method for undetected_chromedriver like there is for normal chromedriver in selenium instead there's add_argument() method which works for unpacked/extracted format but doesn't seem to work for .crx format and gives the error "Failed to load extension from: {extension directory/extenion.crx}. Manifest file is missing or unreadable" when I try to load it in the .crx format.

So I want to know is there any way to load a chrome extension in .crx format within the undetected_chromedriver?

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--load-extension={Extension_Path/extension.crx}')
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', { 'extensions.ui.developer_mode': True })
driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, options=options)
driver.get("chrome-extension://{extension_content_directory/popup.html}")
```

The extension in question is called Sweet VPN.